# How do you create a nested table in R?

Tags: r, package

I know there is a way to easily do this using a package... I found the package a couple of months ago and did it then. However, I didn't write down the link at the time, and now I can't find the solution again for the life of me!

My question is: how do you create a nested table in **R**? For example, I have a data table of individuals. Every row is a different person. Every column contains a variable such as age, gender, height, etc.

I know that using the table command I can do something like this: table(data$gender, data$ageCategory).

This would make a 2 x 2 table with the counts inside.

However, I would like to make a nested table, analogous to the one here (ignore the final column with the totals): http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/ror/32/2/images/ror_32_2_199_tbl1a.gif

I.e., I would like to make a table with gender as the columns, then with the rows as age category, and within each row, additional rows with height category.

I found a package that did this easily and now I can't find it again!

Thanks for anyone who can help. This is a somewhat silly question but I thought I might have more luck here. Perhaps "nested table" isn't really the proper name for this.

Comment: I think you are looking for column and row names. Try searching for that, because a nested table would be a separate table within a cell of the table (I think), so probably wouldn't give you what you're looking for. Oh... I didn't read the rest. You are probably looking for merged cells. Sorry about that.

Comment: What is your definition of "nested table" ?  A row cannot contain a row.  Either you want a multidimensional array or perhaps a `list` variable, e.g.  `myfile` with elements `$age,$gender,$height` and then each such element could have subelements, e.g. `age$foo, age$bar` .

Comment: Do you want to produce a nested table as output to e.g. LaTex, or do you want to use a nested table as a mean to store data (which can be done easily using ordinary data.frames).

Comment: Thanks everyone! You're right - it's not really called a "nested" table. I finally found a way to do it using the "ftable" (flat contingency table) and "xtabs" commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example dataset (which is always a good idea to use in your question):

```
dat = data.frame(value = runif(100),
                 age = round(runif(100, min = 9, max = 11)) , 
                 gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 school = sample(c("Public", "Private"), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

And now to produce something useful along the lines of the example table you posted:

```
library(plyr)
tab = count(dat, c("age", "gender", "school"))
# The contents of tab:
#    age gender  school freq
# 1    9 Female Private    6
# 2    9 Female  Public    6
# 3    9   Male Private    7
# 4    9   Male  Public    8
# 5   10 Female Private   11
# 6   10 Female  Public   13
# 7   10   Male Private   10
# 8   10   Male  Public   14
# 9   11 Female Private    3
# 10  11 Female  Public   11
# 11  11   Male Private    3
# 12  11   Male  Public    8
```

And to produce a table for latex, take a look at the xtable package. For Word etc it is probably easiest to perform some manual operations on the output of count.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also finally found the package that I had been thinking of - it's called MASS. I used the data you provided to do the following: 

library(MASS) ;
ftable(xtabs(formula = ~school + gender + age, data = dat))

Comment: Alternatively, with base R only: as.data.frame(table(dat$gender, dat$school, dat$age))

Answer (score 2):

You can pass more than two variables into `table` in order to get counts of the dataset split more ways.  This is a modification of an example for the `table` help page.

```
counts <- with(airquality, table(
  OzCategory = cut(airquality$Ozone, seq(0, 180, 20)),
  Month,
  TempHi = Temp > 75
))
print(counts, zero.print = ".")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasn't aware that this was possible - will definitely come in handy in the future!